# SSRS - Report Website Error processing Dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, business-intelligence

After adding a T-SQL query-based dataset to a report and deploying it, the report stopped working because of the following error.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'NewDataset'.
>   (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information about this error
>   navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable
>   remote errors

Datasource : Cube + SQL DB
Dataset: Cube + SQL DB

Table on the report: Most columns filled from Cube DB. Added one more column connected T-SQL DB.

Before adding T-SQL dataset, report was showing perfectly on the site. The SSRS previews report perfectly.

The report uses a shared dataset that connects to a SQL shared datasource.

Comment: Often, t-sql datasets will fail when deployed due to security problems. Ensure that the account that the SSRS reports run under have the appropriate security for all of the db objects in the t-sql dataset.

Comment: How do I check for that please?

Comment: First, identify how the report connecting to the SQL data. If it uses a shared data source, find the data source in the Report Manager. Click the down arrow located on the right side of the data source and choose "Manage". In the properties, you can determine what account is used to connect to SQL.

Comment: On the SQL database, ensure that the account used for the data source has the security privileges required to access the database objects used in the query (maybe the tables referenced in the query, or the stored procedure, depending on what the source of your dataset is).

Comment: Embedded dataset connects to shared dataset that connects to a SQL shared datasource. On Report Manager/Datasource/SQLDatasource/Security/ I have "Credentials stored securely in the report server" with username and password. I right clicked that sql db and under properties/permissions, I see that username in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your dataset based on a query or a stored procedure? If it's a query, does it use stored procedures or functions?

Comment: Query, no store procedure/functions, just inner joining a bunch of tables and uses Case statement

Comment: Are you able to connect to the db via SSMS using the login and pw used for the SSRS data source and test the query from SSMS?

Comment: You are right, I logged in as that user and gave me permission error for the table/schema I was using in my query. I will see if giving permission fixes this issue.

Comment: Ok thanks. Let me know, and if that's the case I'll write it all up as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. Now, the dataset processes. The web user did not have access to tables I was using the query. After giving permission, the dataset processed. You can write a nice answer that exmplains this for future purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, dataset queries will fail when deployed due to security problems. Ensure that the account that the SSRS reports run under have the appropriate security for all of the db objects used in the dataset query.

Find the data source in the Report Manager. Click the down arrow located on the right side of the data source and choose "Manage". In the properties, you can determine what account is used to connect to SQL.

On the SQL database, ensure that the account used for the data source has the security privileges required to access the database objects used in the query (maybe the tables referenced in the query, or the stored procedure, depending on what the source of your dataset is).

Try connecting to SSMS with the same account that the data source is using, and run the same query. The errors that you get during this process will help identify where security privileges are needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with the same error message, the root of the issue is not from the security perspective, but from the database view related to the report.  Here's how I found out:

1. Run the same report from Report Builder: from Report Manager, click the report that produces error. You might have to provide additional parameters depending on your report, then click View Report
2. You should now see the same error message. The content of the message is the same in the first sentence; but the second sentence on it will show in more detail the cause of the error. In my case I have a view that queries columns not existing (because I deleted) in the table. When I update the view, it works again with the report.